# can I use 2 bootstrap for 2 section in laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

Can I use 2 bootstrap css for 1 project
for example, my theme using botstrap 3.x

and I want to use botstrap 4.x in some div.

```
<div>
 // using bootstrao 3.x
</div>

<div>
 // using bootstrao 3.x
</div>
```

Comment: Not on the same page you can't. Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: Doubtful. If you try to include the CSS for both bootstrap 3.x and 4.x and there are duplicate declarations, the one that is included last will supersede the first. If you somehow could edit/customize the css files to use unique prefix/suffix, then you would be able to do something like `<div class="bs3_row">`, then `<div class="bs4_row"`, etc. But that's a lot of overhead/effor for not much benefit.

Comment: Not without running into multiple duplicate declarations. What's your thought process behind wanting to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to stick to particular bootstrap and use it throughout your project. As the functionality of every bootstrap differs from one another, it is not a good practice to use different bootstraps for 1 project.

Also, having 2 bootstraps in 1 project can result to conflicts because of many classes of the bootstrap library have the same name.